# Downvoted post remains in my rep history after post is deleted

Tags: support

I downvoted some answers two days ago.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030315/im-looking-for-an-english-dictionary-in-json-format/) was deleted 18 hours ago at 2-22 .... 07:13:47Z. Most of the downvotes were reversed as the answers and later the question was deleted. However two remain there. We are now in the new day and the rep hasn't been adjusted. I'm wondering if this is a glitch?

This is when showed removed posts is not enabled:

[image]

This is when showed removed posts is enabled:

[image]

Comment: The problem is still there. I'm asking if it is a bug?

Answer (score 7):

When the post is deleted it doesn't remove the -1 for the downvote, it *adds* a +1 that reverses it.  Also note that it is only showed if "show removed posts" is enabled.

Comment: The other ones disappeared? And my showed removed posts is not enabled

Comment: You're right, the rep is correct, it's more a glitch of why it is still appearing there.. I've updated my question